# Acquiring maximum absolute values of certain column values in python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```
year      num
1982      -4
1983      -7
1983      5
1984      -1
1986      0
...
2008      47
2009      -5
2009      -2
2009      17
2009      84
```

I have sorted `df` by `year` and then `num` in an ascending order, as shown. I aim to find the maximum absolute value of `num` of each `year`, and then create a new column `new`, explained by `num` divided by the maximum absolute value of `num` of the `year` the row is located at.

Hence, the first and the last five values of `df` should look like this:

```
year      num       newnum
1982      -4        -1
1983      -7        -1
1983      5         -0.7143
1984      -1        -1
1986      0         0
...
2008      47        1
2009      -5        -0.0595
2009      -2        -0.0238
2009      17        0.2024
2009      84        1
```

I thought about creating an absolute value column separately to do a column-scale division, e.g.

```
df['absnum'] = df.num.abs()
```

and then find its `max` value, but then I run into a problem of not being able to categorize those `absnum` values by `year`. Is there an efficient way to calculate `newnum` for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for get maximum absolute values with divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df['new'] = df['num'].div(df['num'].abs().groupby(df['year']).transform('max'))
print (df)
   year  num       new
0  1982   -4 -1.000000
1  1983   -7 -1.000000
2  1983    5  0.714286
3  1984   -1 -1.000000
4  1986    0       NaN
5  2008   47  1.000000
6  2009   -5 -0.059524
7  2009   -2 -0.023810
8  2009   17  0.202381
9  2009   84  1.000000
```

With new column:

```
df['absnum'] = df.num.abs()

df['new'] = df['num'].div(df.groupby('year')['absnum'].transform('max'))
print (df)
   year  num  absnum       new
0  1982   -4       4 -1.000000
1  1983   -7       7 -1.000000
2  1983    5       5  0.714286
3  1984   -1       1 -1.000000
4  1986    0       0       NaN
5  2008   47      47  1.000000
6  2009   -5       5 -0.059524
7  2009   -2       2 -0.023810
8  2009   17      17  0.202381
9  2009   84      84  1.000000
```

Last if necessary replace missing values by `0`:

```
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(0)
```